# How do I query non-unique values only

Tags: ms-access

I have a table like in the image below.
I'd like to make a query that returns only those rows that contain a non-unique value in field `number as text`.

First I tried to get the opposite (unique values only) with `Distinct` but that returns only the values from field `number as text` while I need to have returned the whole row.
But in the end it is the non-unique values that I am after, so I am stuck.

[image]

The desired outcome is as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Already found the answer:
**Criteria:**
`In (SELECT [number as text] FROM [Tabel1] As Tmp GROUP BY [number as text] HAVING Count(*)>1 )`